# Utility Bar API Unable To Obtain Eclosing Utility Id

Tags: lightning-aura-components, utility-bar

I am working on an aura component for a utility bar, and specifically trying to add a handler via the `onUtilityClick` method of the [`<lightning:utilityBarAPI>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:utilityBarAPI/documentation) component. My understanding based on the documentation is that I need to find the `utilityId` of the utility onto which I would like to add this handler. To do so, I tried calling the [`getEnclosingUtilityId()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_getEnclosingUtilityId.htm) method, but it keeps returning false *even though I am calling it from within a utility*.

> Returns the ID of the enclosing utility, or false if not within a utility.

When I open the below utility in the utility bar, I see a log like below:

> utilityId false

I initially tried calling `onUtilityClick` within the promise callback, but since I am getting a `false` value anyway, I tried moving it out and not even specifying a `utilityId` value. That resulted in an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid or missing utilityId `false`

**Why is my component, when calling this API from a utility, retreving a `utilityId` which indicates I am not within a utility?**

---

Below is the basic structure of my code.

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.demo}" />
    <lightning:utilityBarAPI aura:id="utilityBarAPI" />
    <lightning:button label="Demo" onclick="{!c.demo}" />
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    demo: function (component, event, helper) {
        const utilityBarAPI = component.find("utilityBarAPI");
        utilityBarAPI.getEnclosingUtilityId().then(function (utilityId) {
            console.log("utilityId", utilityId);
        });
        utilityBarAPI.onUtilityClick({
            eventHandler: function () {
                console.log("onUtilityClick");
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a know bug that makes all calls to `lightning:utilityBarAPI` fail when first performed in the context of the init handler.

There are two solutions to fix that:

1. obviously, don't use `lightning:utilityBarAPI` in the init handler :)
2. delay the call to `lightning:utilityBarAPI` methods with a `setTimeout` (works but risky because duration is unpredictable)

Updated code:

**Component**

```xml
<aura:component access="global" implements="lightning:utilityItem">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.handleInit}" />

    <lightning:utilityBarAPI aura:id="utilityBarAPI" />
    <lightning:button label="Demo" onclick="{!c.handleDemoClick}" />
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```js
({
    handleInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            helper.callUtilityBarApi(component);
        }, 500);
    },

    handleDemoClick: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.callUtilityBarApi(component);
    }
})
```

**Helper**

```js
({
    callUtilityBarApi : function(component) {
        const utilityBarAPI = component.find("utilityBarAPI");
        utilityBarAPI.getEnclosingUtilityId().then(function (utilityId) {
            console.log("utilityId", utilityId);
        });

        utilityBarAPI.onUtilityClick({
            eventHandler: function () {
                console.log("onUtilityClick");
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: It did fail even when I tried moving the call to button click. I'll try this out and get back to you on the results in my org.

Comment: Adding the `setTimeout` did not work for me. Did you get a value for `utilityId`? Also, it does not appear you passed this value into the `onUtilityClick` call. Did either work when you implement this utility?

Comment: Yes, it works consistently for me. `utilityId` is somehting like "281:0" and `onUtilityClick` is triggered as expected. Did you try with the exact code I provided? I realized that I used the `lightning:utilityItem` interface instead of `flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes` but I doubt that this could be an issue.

Comment: I suggest that you get rid of the init handler and just try it with the button click.

Comment: @AdrianLarson did you try with `lightning:utilityItem` and just the button click handler?

Comment: It appears that the secret sauce was removing the code from the init handler.

Comment: Nice, I'm glad that you figured it out. Hopefully that will get fixed.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Perhaps we just needed `$A.getCallback` around the function(), like: `setTimeout($A.getCallback(() => helper.setUtilityId(component) ), 500);`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to call the method when component renders using handler on `render` event. This event is also fired when component re-renders so you will need to have a flag and wrap your code to execute it only one time.

**Component**

```html
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}" />
    <lightning:utilityBarAPI aura:id="utilityBarAPI" />
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```js
({
    onRender: function(component, event, helper) {
        const utilityBarAPI = component.find('utilityBarAPI');
        utilityBarAPI.getEnclosingUtilityId().then((utilityId) => {
            console.log(`utilityId: ${utilityId}`);
        });
        utilityBarAPI.onUtilityClick({
            eventHandler: () => {
                console.log('onUtilityClick');
            }
        });
    }
})
```